# 2 buttons on the same line

Tags: html, css, button

I just cant get them on the same line, anyone know what I can do?
I'm trying to put both buttons on the top line and both expand under them
I've looked at a couple other posts about this (display:inline-block;, etc, might have put them in thr wrong spot though) but I cant seem to get any of it working

this is the code:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 40%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.button {
  display: inline;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 37%;
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsible">button</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>text</p>
</div>

<button class="collapsible">button</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: in CSS you have the selector `.button` while you have no element with this class. By default buttons are inline-elements in the first place. The issue you having is caused because of the div's between the buttons. those are block-level-elements and as such cause a linebreak.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest getting familiar with Flexbox. Based on what you're trying to achieve with your layout of buttons next to each other and corresponding text underneath the associated button, you'd be much better off thinking in terms of containers and items that go into those containers rather than trying to write specific CSS rules for every element. Your brain will thank you when it hurts less.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 37%;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <div class="item">
    <button class="collapsible">button</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <button class="collapsible">button</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now, those buttons are right up next to each other but I think you'll be able to take it from here.

I'm including a link to JSFiddle with this working. It also includes your JavaScript so you can see the collapse effect. https://jsfiddle.net/ods0j65t/

Answer (score 0):

Put your `HTML` code in another div,

```
<div class="container">

 <button class="collapsible">button</button>
 <div class="content">
  <p>text</p>
 </div>

 <button class="collapsible">button</button>
 <div class="content">
  <p>text</p>
 </div>

</div>
```

and add in `CSS`

```
.container {
 display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work as the OP designed the application. A single flex container will make the buttons and the text areas all show up on the same row. The intention was that the buttons appear on the same row but the corresponding text areas still remain underneath the buttons. Therefore, you need more than just one container.

Comment: Then use 'grid' instead of 'flex' and update your CSS.